# How "clusterable" is an affinity matrix?

Tags: clustering, similarities, metric

In my problem I have some affinity matrices computed from different similarity functions. I'd like to know if there is a measure that assesses how "clusterable" these matrices are. In other words, how close they are to block diagonal for some permutation of their rows/columns. As an example, take the following:

[image: https://calculatedcontent.com/2012/10/09/spectral-clustering/]

One can visually see that the matrices on the left are "blockier" that the ones on the right, which characterize a good and a bad similarity measure, respectively. How can I qualitatively assess the similarity measure on a given dataset just by using its affinity matrix? Any help is welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: There are algorithms/methods (quite different btw) to do block diagonalization. Some researchers consider BD as pre-clustering tool to assess the number of clusters, and some consider it as a kind of clustering.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns! Thanks, but I am actually not interested in block diagonalizing the matrices. I'd just want to know if there is a measure that tells how "blocky" they are (which would entail a "how good the affinity measure is").

Comment: I see. A coefficient of block-diagonalness. I've never encountered one. I'm interested in it too but haven't start a search. If you come to know one, please let me know. The coefficient would measure both diagolness and blockness, for these are not identical notions.

Comment: Well, that's what a said " for some permutation of their rows/columns", since a matrix could be blocky and not diagonal, but it becomes diagonal when a row/column permutation is applied (just compare the two matrices on the left). I hope it makes sense.

Comment: And sure, I'll keep you posted! Thanks for the help!